# Pandas merge operation for nearest date variation + / - 3 days

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, merge

I have 2 dataframes for transactions  :

Left :

```
        code        debit       credit         reference        payment date

    1   112133      6,31,964.51 0           MH20181000022319    18.09.2018      
    2   112133      6,29,161.51 0           MH20181000022340    12.09.2018      
    3   112133      2,78,288.51 0           MH20181000022341    27.10.2018      
    4   112133      0           3,13,599.51 MH20181000022502    13.11.2018      
    5   112133      3,16,683.00 0           MH20181000022503    22.07.2018      
    6   112133      3,27,332.00 0           MH20181000022504    02.12.2018
```

Right :-

```
        code        DR          CR          reference          trans date

    1   112133      7,37,964.51 0           345                 24.09.2018      
    2   112133      0           6,31,964.51 456                 20.09.2018      
    3   112133      1,23,434.00 0           567                 13.05.2018      
    4   112133      3,13,599.51 0           420                 09.03.2018      
    5   112133      0           3,16,683.00 890                 19.01.2018      
    6   112133      3,27,332.00 0           123                 19.01.2018
```

I want to perform the join operation using pandas merge / merge_asof on :

left columns = ['debit', 'payment date']

right columns = ['credit', 'trans date']

The problem is payment date don't match exactly everytime, hence I need to consider variation of + / - 3 days for a given date of left row to right row.

Hence, the results should, ideally match the 1 left row with 2 right row.

I started referring merge_asof & merge_ordered, please suggest ?

That would be very helpful.

Comment: I referred TimeDelta, & it solved my problem 50%, as merge_asof only supports single columns join, please suggest how to use multi columns in merge_asof ?

Answer (score 1):

When working with continuous series (not categorical).  A technique that can be used is turn it into categorical using `pd.cut()`.

1. work out start and end dates from *left* and *right*.  construct the *bins* as being every 6 days (almost equivalent to +/- 3 days)
2. `assign()` a new column *datebin* to *left* and *right* which is categorised dates
3. *join* on the value and the *datebin*

Most of the code is just parsing the text you pasted in your question.

```
data = """idx        code        debit       credit         reference        payment date
    1   112133      6,31,964.51  0           MH20181000022319    18.09.2018      
    2   112133      6,29,161.51  0           MH20181000022340    12.09.2018      
    3   112133      2,78,288.51  0           MH20181000022341    27.10.2018      
    4   112133      0           3,13,599.51  MH20181000022502    13.11.2018      
    5   112133      3,16,683.00  0           MH20181000022503    22.07.2018      
    6   112133      3,27,332.00  0           MH20181000022504    02.12.2018  """

a = [[t.strip().replace(",", "") for t in re.split("  ",l) if t!=""]  for l in [re.sub("([0-9]+[ ])*(.*)", r"\2", l) for l in data.split("\n")]]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(a[1:], columns=a[0]).drop("idx", axis=1)
df1["payment date"] = pd.to_datetime(df1["payment date"])
data = """idx        code        DR          CR          reference          trans date
    1   112133      7,37,964.51  0           345                 24.09.2018      
    2   112133      0           6,31,964.51  456                 20.09.2018      
    3   112133      1,23,434.00  0           567                 13.05.2018      
    4   112133      3,13,599.51  0           420                 09.03.2018      
    5   112133      0           3,16,683.00  890                 19.01.2018      
    6   112133      3,27,332.00  0           123                 19.01.2018"""
a = [[t.strip().replace(",", "") for t in re.split("  ",l) if t!=""]  for l in [re.sub("([0-9]+[ ])*(.*)", r"\2", l) for l in data.split("\n")]]

df2 = pd.DataFrame(a[1:], columns=a[0]).drop("idx", axis=1)
df2["trans date"] = pd.to_datetime(df2["trans date"])

# NB previous pd.to_datetime()
# get min and max dates from both dataframes, then create a series of bins for every 6 days
# approximates to +/- 3 days
bins = pd.date_range(min(df1["payment date"].min(), df2["trans date"].min()), 
              max(df1["payment date"].max(), df2["trans date"].max()), freq="6D")


dfm = df1.assign(datebin=pd.cut(df1["payment date"], bins=bins))\
    .merge(df2.assign(datebin=pd.cut(df2["trans date"], bins=bins)), 
           left_on=["debit","datebin"], right_on=["CR","datebin"])
```

**output**

```
 code_x      debit credit       reference_x payment date                   datebin  code_y DR         CR reference_y trans date
 112133  631964.51      0  MH20181000022319   2018-09-18  (2018-09-16, 2018-09-22]  112133  0  631964.51         456 2018-09-20
```